# Stable Dold-Kan correspondence and symmetric group actions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, model-categories, stable-homotopy, ring-spectra

There exists a Quillen equivalence between $HRModSpectra$ (model category of ring spectra over Eilenberg-MacLane spectra $EM(R)$, where $R$ is a commutative ring, with stable model structure) and $Ch$ (model category of unbounded chain complexes of $R$-modules).

I was wondering what the Quillen functors are that give the above Quillen equivalence.

One can start with an unbounded chain complex $X$ and apply the Dold-Kan functor $\Gamma$ to chain complex $X_{\geq 0}$ to get a simplicial abelian group $\Gamma(X_{\geq 0})$, and then consider $\Gamma(X[-n]_{\geq0})$ (shifting $X$ to the left by n places, truncating and then applying $\Gamma$). This way one gets an $\Omega$-spectrum $Y$ = {${Y_{0}, Y_{1},...}$}, with $Y_{n} = \Gamma(X[-n]_{\geq0})$.

How does then one proceed to prove that $Y$  is a symmetric spectrum? For that one needs an action of  symmetric group $S_{n}$ on $Y_{n}$. Now each $Y_{i}$ is in fact as a simplicial set equivalent  to $\prod K(\pi_{k}(Y_{n}), k)$  and $K(\pi_{n}(Y_{n}), n)$ has an $S_{n}$ action, though I'm not sure if this action will satisfy the compatibility conditions that are required of a symmetric spectrum.

Comment: Careful: people mean a different thing with "stable Dold-Kan correspondence" (usually that in a stable category (co)simplicial objects are equivalent to filtered objects)

Comment: ok! I was following the terminology from this ncatlab page  theorem 2.2 ;[link](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stable+Dold-Kan+correspondence#Kan63)

Comment: The Quillen equivalences were proven explicitly by Brooke Shipley and Stefan Schwede. See *$H\mathbb{Z}$-algebra spectra are differential graded algebras* by Shipley or *Stable model categories are categories of modules* by Schwede and Shipley.

Comment: @LennartMeier thanks for the references and sorry for the late reply, I found what I needed in appendix of Stable model categories are categories of modules by Schwede and Shipley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting a CW answer so that this doesn't remain open and unanswered, even though the OP said in the comments he figured it out. I just posted an [answer to an analogous question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/334622/11540) and in doing so found this question. The relevant paper is "[Stable model categories are categories of modules](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/classTopFinal.pdf)" by Schwede and Shipley. The construction the OP describes (Dold-Kan plus shift) is on page 39, where it is also shown how to make this into an $HR$-module (via the Alexander-Whitney map). Remark B.1.10 discusses the symmetric group actions. This functor $\mathcal{H}$ takes a chain complexes to a *naive* $HR$-module, not a symmetric spectrum. It is not an extension of the usual Eilenberg-MacLane functor, $H$. The authors claim that there is no way to make $\mathcal{H}R$ into a symmetric spectrum that is level equivalent to $HR$. This explains why the Quillen equivalence has to zig-zag through naive $HR$-modules.